# BrokenPipeError celery.bin.base in out

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, aws-fargate

We have Ec2 fargate instance running on AWS,   there is a celery worker which is running by

```
celery -A app status
```

Repeatedly we are getting the following error for this instance

```
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
      File "celery", line 8, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
        _main()
      File "celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
        cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
      File "celery/bin/celery.py", line 499, in execute_from_commandline
        super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
      File "celery/bin/base.py", line 305, in execute_from_commandline
        return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
      File "celery/bin/celery.py", line 491, in handle_argv
        return self.execute(command, argv)
      File "celery/bin/celery.py", line 419, in execute
        ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
      File "celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in run_from_argv
        sys.argv if argv is None else argv, command)
      File "celery/bin/base.py", line 393, in handle_argv
        return self(*args, **options)
      File "celery/bin/base.py", line 253, in __call__
        ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
      File "celery/bin/control.py", line 239, in run
        nodecount, text.pluralize(nodecount, 'node')))
      File "celery/bin/base.py", line 413, in out
        print(s, file=fh or self.stdout)
```

Any insights into it?

Comment: At the moment of writing this Celery is not good solution if you __insist__ on using AWS Fargate. Some future versions of Celery may be able to schedule execution of tasks on Fargate, but that seems far away. What you can do is to wrap running something on Fargate from a Celery task, but you still have to run Celery worker(s) on few EC2 instances, or ECS nodes.

Comment: Hi Dejan, could you extend your answer and explain why it is not a good solution at this moment.